# Parse.com says "no data yet" with actual device

Tags: android, cloud, parse-platform

I am new to Parse.com and trying to the quick start project. I am following each and every step to build an app on android platform. But I am getting "no data yet" message everytime I click on Test `button`.
What I've done so far is:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Parse.initialize(this, "AMRjGNY53W2HFZILS7M64rZy3b8mSz3qGkf1KeOE","xquKy2rT8FSeFYCd8A8mIVOCqqO5SlSMrCwlZ0ux");
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("foo", "bar");
    testObject.saveInBackground();
}}
```

My Application class is :

```
package com.example.hello1;

import android.app.Application;
import com.parse.Parse;

public class ParseApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Add your initialization code here
        Parse.initialize(this, "AMRjGNY53W2HFZILS7M64rZy3b8mSz3qGkf1KeOE", "xquKy2rT8FSeFYCd8A8mIVOCqqO5SlSMrCwlZ0ux");
    }
```

and the manifest file :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:name="ParseApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hello1.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

After running the app when I click on test on parse.com, it says no data yet. !!

I don't understand what wrong I'm doing !!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Go to your manifest file and make sure that you application node is referencing your Java file.

For example you have your application class below

public class MyApplication extends Application
{...}

in the AndroidManifest you need something like this...

```
 <application
  android:name="com.example.test.MyApplication"
```

That way your application file can be called by the application. =)

**Make sure you use your fully qualified class name.**

Answer (score 1):

You can just try to see what happens when you try to save the object.
The code below is an example to show how can you do that with a save callback.

I also encountered this problem and when i implemented this method, i found out that i get an https connection error. Later i see that my device's hosts file is blocking the api call.

```
    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("foo", "bar");
    Log.e("PARSE.COM","DOWNLOAD STARTED");
    testObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.e("PARSE.COM","FAILED" + e.getMessage());
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("PARSE.COM","SUCCESS");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and try again, you need put Parse.initialize in the first line

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Parse.initialize(this, "AMRjGNY53W2HFZILS7M64rZy3b8mSz3qGkf1KeOE", "xquKy2rT8FSeFYCd8A8mIVOCqqO5SlSMrCwlZ0ux")
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("foo", "bar");
    testObject.saveInBackground();
}}
```

Comment: I added that permission as well but it was not appearing on the website before. I have edited it now. Still not working.

Comment: Check this answer again, put Parse.initialize in the first

Comment: Check your parse key are correct... Parse is easy for use and I also use this code to work .... Good luck :)

Comment: I tried launching the app on emulator and it works But when I try launching it on real device, only then it creates problem and not saving the data. Is there an specific reason ??

Comment: Maybe you change "TestObject" to others table name and try again

Comment: Yep, Same problem. Not working on real device.can add other objects with emulator but not with real device.